# Axios not saving session cookies

Tags: node.js, reactjs, session, axios, session-cookies

I'm currently working on a web app where I use Axios to communicate with the backend server. I'm using an Express server with a session to authenticate users and protect certain routes.

When I test the API endpoints with Postman or Insomnia, I can log in and access the protected route without any issues. However, when I try to access the same protected route from the deployed React app, I get a 401 Unauthorized error.

After some debugging, I found out that the session object is empty when I make a request from the React app, and req.session.isAuth is undefined in the middleware that checks for authentication.

I suspect that Axios is not saving the cookies, even though I added withCredentials: true to the Axios config.

Here are some relevant code snippets:

Frontend:

```js
const api = axios.create({
  baseURL: API_BASE_URL,
  withCredentials: true,
});
```

Backend:

```js
const sessionOptions = {
  secret: tokenSecret,
  keys: [tokenSecret],
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false,
  cookie: {
    secure: true,
    httpOnly: true,
    sameSite: 'none',
    maxAge: 3600000,
  },
};
app.use(session(sessionOptions));

app.use(morgan('dev'));

const corsOptions = {
  credentials: true,
  origin: NODE_ENV === 'production' ? PRO_URL : LOCAL_URL,
};
app.use(cors(corsOptions));
```

I also tried adding `app.set('trust proxy', 1)`to the backend server, but it didn't solve the issue. (but it i think make the protected route access accessbile to me through axios react app only one time)

How can I fix this problem and make sure that Axios is saving the cookies correctly? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: (However i edited the session and cookies config and maybe i ruined it up but i tried too much maybe i got some luck but i didn't)

Comment: when i login i only do this
req.session.isAuth = true

Answer (score 0):

I've been through this, I believe I've seen something similar around here, in this case, i verified that the requests with the definition of `withCredentials: true` already in the api sends requests for the same domain, so the problem may be in in the definition your API with axios, try creating the API with only the baseURL and passing `withCredentials: true` in the requests.